# Get the same pixels of two raster

Tags: r, statistics, raster, pixel

I have a question about a methodology. So i have two raster. One raster is from 2018 and the other from 2019. Now I want to see if the same pixels from 2018 also appear in 2019. So I just want to find out whether the same pixels are simply available again in the following year.
Until now I would have done it by converting my 2018 values ​​into 1 and NA and then multiplying the 2018 raster by 2019. so all the same pixels would be retained in 2019 and which are not identical to NA. at least that's my theory.

My question relates to whether there isn't a package or a more elegant way of finding out what the two rasters have in common?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `?terra::all.equal`:

*Compare two SpatRasters for (near) equality.
First the attributes of the objects are compared. If these are the same, a (perhaps small) sample of the raster cells is compared as well.
The sample size used can be increased with the maxcell argument. You can set it to Inf, but for large rasters your computer may not have sufficient memory.*

Example:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.7

x <- sqrt(1:100)
mat <- matrix(x, 10, 10)
r1 <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, xmin=0, vals = x)
r2 <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, xmin=0, vals = mat)

all.equal(r1, r2)
#> [1] "Component \"lyr.1\": Mean relative difference: 0.3858482"
all.equal(r1, r1*1)
#> [1] TRUE
```

This sound like a method which should be applicable to your problem without having to reclassify manually.

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
r1 <- s[[1]]
set.seed(0)
r1[sample(ncell(r1), 1000)] <- NA
r2 <- s[[2]]
r2[sample(ncell(r2), 1000)] <- NA
```

Your question is not very clear. To assure that both rasters have values or NA in the same cells, you could do

```
r <- c(r1, r2)
m <- sum(r)
x <- mask(r, m)
```

To compare the values in the two rasters, you can do

```
rc <- r1 == r2
```

To find out if the same cells are NA, you can do

```
xna <- is.na(r) |> sum()
```

And you get values of 0 (never NA), 1 (NA in one year), and 2 (always NA). If you want to distinguish the "1" cases to know which year was NA, you can instead do

```
u <- is.na(r) |> unique(as.raster=TRUE)
```

`u` has four cases "0_0" is never NA, etc. See

```
cats(u)[[1]]
#  ID label red green
#1  0   0_0   0     0
#2  1   0_1   0     1
#3  2   1_0   1     0
#4  3   1_1   1     1
```

And

```
freq(u)
#  layer value count
#1     1   0_0  5905
#2     1   0_1   872
#3     1   1_0   872
#4     1   1_1   128
```